# Converting list data to string

Tags: c++

I am trying to add all the elements from my list (they are a template type) in a string, so I can print this string.
Here is my struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next;
    Node(const T& a_data, Node* next_value = NULL) :
        data(a_data) {
            next = next_value;
        }
};
```

Here is my code:

```
string printList() 
{
    string printing = "";
    Node * current = my_list;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= num_items); i++)
    {
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            printing = printing + current->data;
            printing = printing + " ";
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return printing;
}
```

Comment: if my_list is an object, it should be Node* current = &my_list;

Comment: Its difficult to know how these two pieces of code relate to each other. What are `my_list` and `num_items` ? I take it `printList` is a meber function of some `list` class?

Comment: Posting bits and pieces of code is not useful to compose a cogent answer. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: OK, you're trying to convert X to Y, which isn't adequately explained as others have pointed out. But more importantly, I don't see a question here at all.

Comment: What is your expectation?